# How to SUM via Group By?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table something like this:

```
ID   Marks  Weightatthistime
1    5          44  
1    5          43 
1    5          41  
2    4          39
2    4          38
```

I want the total marks obtained by the IDs, so I want my query to return: 9. 
I know I could do a:

```
select ID, sum(Marks) from table group by 1
```

but I simply just want the total sum and not another mini table. The table is aggregated at this level and there's no way for me to change it.

Comment: What if there are different values for `Marks` on the **same** `ID`?

Comment: that's possible.

Comment: So, if the second row had a Marks = 3, what would be the result you expect?

Comment: @LaxMandis - So, how do you determine the difference duplicated scores and scores that just happen to be the same value?  Are there other columns you're not showing us?  I think you need to explain why some rows are duplicates, how to determine that they are duplicates, how you want to handle all possible eventualities : https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: made the edit. The duplicates occur due to each ID having multiple body weights.

Answer (score 1):

Use subquery :

```
select id, sum(marks)
from (select distinct id, marks
      from table t
     ) t
group by id;
```

If you want only `sum` then use only `sum(marks)` :

```
select sum(marks)
from (select distinct id, marks
      from table t
      ) t;
```

Comment: The first query is identical to the one in the question

Answer (score 0):

use distinct

```
   select sum( distinct Marks) from table




  with cte as
(
select 1 id, 5 as m union all
select 1,5 union all
select 1,5 union all
select 2,4 union all
select 2,4
) select sum(distinct m) from cte
```

but if multiple user have same number then follow subquery method that @Yogesh shown

output

9

Comment: Marks could be the same for different users.

Comment: @LaxMandis you asked for 9 result

Comment: @LaxMandis in that case subquery use is safe

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should work with any ANSI SQL engine.

```
Select ID, Marks, Weightatthistime, (Select Sum(Marks) From Table1) SumAllMarks
   From Table1
```

This will put 9 on each record.

Answer (score 0):

> SELECT sum(DISTINCT marks) FROM table;

You can use this query to get the sum of the distinct mark values.